# Avoid dialogue by opening a shell script?

Tags: command-line, scripts

When i have an executable script and i runs it by double-clicking it
in Gnome.

It opens a dialoguebox that asks, what is intended to do:

- execute in terminal
- view
- cancel
- execute

Is there a way to avoid this question in for certain selected scripts?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- In nautilus goto Edit **→** Preferences and then select Behavior tab.
- Under **Executable Text files** select "View executable text files when they are opened" or select "Run executable text files when they are opened".

  [image]
- Now that dialog will get disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In Nautilus... `Edit->Preferences->Behavior` and look under **Executable Text Files**.